# Combining substrings in C# with a custom format?

Tags: c#, substring

Part of an app I'm creating in C# replaces certain substrings in a string with a value in square brackets like `[11]`. Often there can be the same value straight after - so I want to reduce the amount of text by combining them into one like `[11,numberOfSame]`

For example, if the string contains:
`blahblah[122][122][122]blahblahblahblah[18][18][18][18]blahblahblah`

The desired new string would be:
`blahblah[122,3]blahblahblahblah[18,4]blahblahblah`

Would anyone know how I would do this? Thanks! :)

Comment: Please post your current code - it is not clear what you have problem with.

Comment: Do you have a list of pre-defined strings you want to replace? This would be different than simply replacing recurring sequences, the latter of which could get rather resource-intensive. If you do have a list, then you may be able to leverage RegularExpressions.

Comment: I do have pre-defined strings that get replaced, but that isn't the problem. The pre-defined strings are replaced with [11] or whatever. It's just they might be recurring like [11][11][11] in which case I would like to shorten it by combining them together like [11,3]. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I've tried finding the ending index of one of the substrings and then working backwards to see if there's any recurring substrings but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace("blahblah[122][122][122]blahblahblahblah[18][18][18][18]blahblahblah",
    @"(\[([^]]+)])(\1)+",
    m => "[" + m.Groups[2].Value + "," + (m.Groups[3].Captures.Count + 1) + "]")
```

Returns:

```
blahblah[122,3]blahblahblahblah[18,4]blahblahblah
```

Explanation of regex:

```
(           Starts group 1
  \[        Matches [
  (         Starts group 2
    [^]]+   Matches 1 or more of anything but ]
  )         Ends group 2
  ]         Matches ]
)           Ends group 1
(           Starts group 3
  \1        Matches whatever was in group 1
)           Ends group 3
+           Matches one or more of group 3
```

Explanation of lambda:

```
m =>                                Accepts a Match object
"[" +                               A [
m.Groups[2].Value +                 Whatever was in group 2
"," +                               A ,
(m.Groups[3].Captures.Count + 1) +  The number of times group 3 matched + 1
"]"                                 A ]
```

I am using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx), which accepts a delegate to compute the replacement value.

Comment: +1. You could change it to `... + (m.Groups[3].Captures.Count==0 ? "" : "," + (m.Groups[3].Captures.Count + 1)) + ...` in order to avoid a `1` count to be added.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Take a closer look at my regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "[122][44][122]blah[18][18][18][18]blah[122][122]";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"((?<firstMatch>\[(.+?)\])(\k<firstMatch>)*)", m => "[" + m.Groups[2].Value + "," + (m.Groups[3].Captures.Count + 1) + "]");
```

Returns:

```
[122,1][44,1][122,1]blah[18,4]blah[122,2]
```

Explanation:

`(?<firstMatch>\[(.+?)\])` Matches the [123] group, names group firstMatch

`\k<firstMatch>` matches whatever text was that was matched by the firstMatch group and adding * matches it zero or more times, giving us our count used in the lambda.

My reference for anything Regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/