# Optimise Regex Replace in a for loop?

Tags: c#, regex, optimization, replace

This is basically a follow-up of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654250/combining-substrings-in-c-sharp-with-a-custom-format). I've been using this code to replace strings contained in an array:

```
string[] replacements = {"these",
                         "words",
                         "will",
                         "get",
                         "replaced"};

string newString = "Hello.replacedthesewordswillgetreplacedreplaced";

for (int j = 0; j < replacements.Length; j++)
{
    newString = Regex.Replace(newBase,
    @"((?<firstMatch>(" + replacements[j] + @"))(\k<firstMatch>)*)",
    m => "[" + j + "," + (m.Groups[3].Captures.Count + 1) + "]");
}
```

After running this code `newString` will be:

> Hello.[4,1][0,1][1,1][2,1][3,1][4,2]

This works fine for small replacements like the one above. It basically replaces the strings instantly - however for large amounts of replacements it tends to slow down.

Can anyone see a way I can optimise it so it replaces faster?

I'm assuming the for loop is what's slowing it down. There are always some strings contained in the array which don't need to be replaced (because they aren't contained in the main `newString` string) so I wonder if there's a way to check that before the for loop. That might turn out to be slower though...

I can't think of a better way to do this so I thought I'd ask. Thanks for the help guys! :)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of methods to try (NB both untested, but I believe they should work and be quicker than your current code).

One using a static compiled Regex:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> Indexes = new Dictionary<string, int> 
{
  { "these", 0 },
  { "words", 1 },
  { "will", 2 },
  { "be", 3 },
  { "replaced", 4 },
};

private static readonly Regex ReplacementRegex = new Regex(string.Join("|", Indexes.Keys), RegexOptions.Compiled)

...
var occurrences = Indexes.Keys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => 0);
return ReplacementRegex.Replace(newString, m => {
  var count = occurences[m.Value];
  occurences[m.Value] = count + 1;
  return "[" + Indexes[m.Value] + "," + count + "]";
});
```

And without a regex:

```
for (int j = 0; j < replacements.Length; j++)
{
  var index = 0;
  var count = 0;
  var replacement = replacements[j];
  while((index = newString.IndexOf(replacement, index)) > -1) 
  {
    count++;
    newString = newString.Substring(0, index) + "[" + j + "," + count + "]" + newString.Substring(index + replacement.Length);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Having a little trouble with the non-regex code though. The text "Hello.replacedthesewordswillgetreplacedreplaced" should be replaced into `Hello.[4,1][0,1][1,1][2,1][3,1][4,2]` but it's turning into `Hello.[4,1][0,1][1,1][2,1][3,1][4,2][4,3]`. The second part should be the number of matching nearby strings that are replaced. This was the trouble I was having when I asked my previous question but Kendall Frey and Sean solved it. Any ideas how I would get that working? Thanks again rich.